# Bitmap only appears in some devices

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have an imageView and a Bitmap which I previously download from internet using an AsyncTask. The images are Google Play app thumbnail, such as this: https://lh6.ggpht.com/y8KPuTX0t3-dXVejh0NKvpPqtseEBiFp65Epyu4r5PxDs4GKLf_5sQaPrh7e5fGPLHxs=w300-rw . As you can see, the dimension of the icon is 300x300, but you can change it modifying the number at the end of the url.

With some devices (Samsung Galaxy S5 or Motorola G for example) the bitmap is correctly loaded into the imageView, but in others is not (unless I change the dimension from 300x300 to 50x50 for example, which it works). I've tried different ways to download the bitmap but it doesn't seem to be the problem. I try to catch any thrown exception but none seems to be thrown (I thought it could be memory problems but nothing about it). The relevant code:

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
HashMap<String, Bitmap> images;
String url;
Context context;
String titleImage;
TextView titleTextView;

/**
 * Constructor. Create a new BitMapDownloader object.
 * @param imageView view where introduce the selected image
 */
public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, String url, HashMap<String, Bitmap> images, Context context, String titleImage, TextView titleTextView) {

    this.images = images;
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);   
    this.url = url;
    this.context = context;
    this.titleImage = titleImage;
    this.titleTextView = titleTextView;
}

@Override
/**
 * Download method. Run in the task thread
 * @param params comes from the execute() call. params[0] is the url
 * @return a Bitmap with the image
 */
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
/**
 * Method to associates the image to the imageView once is downloaded
 */
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

    try{        
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {

            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();

            if (imageView != null) {

                if(bitmap!=null){

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    images.put(url, bitmap);
                    titleTextView.setText(titleImage);
                    ImageDownloader.doAnimation(imageView, context);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Error", " Crazy Error:" + e);
    }
}


public static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Error", "Error:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

I execute this async task by:

```
    public void downloadAndSetImage(Context context, String url, ImageView imageView, String titleImage, TextView titleTextView) {

    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView, url, images, context, titleImage, titleTextView);

    if(!images.containsKey(url)){

        task.execute(url);
    }

    else{

        imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(url));
        titleTextView.setText(titleImage);
        doAnimation(imageView, context);
    }
}
```

The imageView is as simple as this:

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/suggestedAppRelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/suggestedAppIconImageView1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I guess the problem comes resizing the bitmap to the imageView. Thats why I tried different approaches like the following before setting the Bitmap to the ImageView but it didn't work:

```
bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), true);
```

Any help or idea would be really great! Cheers!

Comment: Try to find the source of the problem. First check if everything with the task to download the image is working as expected. You can save the bitmap to check if dimensions are fine. If everything is fine with the bitmap debug the code that scales the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

try to set   myBitmap.setDensity(320);

that helped in my case.
also I had to do:
 BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),output);

but i dont see a place in your code where u may need it, just for info.
Anyhow setDensity may help

greets
chris